# Django: How to Set Default Field Value By Model Method

Tags: python, django

I have a simple Model. I want to calculate a default value for one of its fields (let's call it score) based on some of the fields **of the same model**:

My ideal way to do it is as so:

```
class ModelA(models.model):
    field_1 = models.IntegerField()
    field_1 = models.IntegerField()
    score = models.IntegerField(default=self.calculate_default())

    def calculate_default(self):
        default = (self.field_1 + self.field_2) / 2
        return default
```

**Problem**: the calculate_default method does not have access to self.
One solution I tried was overriding the save() method. The problem is that it prevents the user to further change the score field.

Another method I searched was to override the **inti** of the class. But according to django it might have consequences if not implemented correctly.

What is the cleanest way to achieve this? How can I set the default of a field to be calculated from other fields of **the same model** such that it could be later changed by the user?

I have a hunch that `classmethod` is the way to go but I haven't been able to pull it off yet.

Comment: THe default can not be a callable that takes a `self`. A `default=...` is a callable without a parameter, or a value.

Comment: Don't use `default` for that. Add the calculation to the model's `save()` method instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the calculate_default method does not have access to self. One solution I tried was overriding the save() method. The problem is that it prevents the user to further change the score field.

Actually its the right approach. But you can put a check in `save()` method if the value of score is empty or not:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.score == None:
       self.score = self.calculate_default()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

FYI, in `classmethod`, you can't access `self` or the `ModelA` object. If the class method you intend to use is something not dependent on the current instance of `ModelA`'s fields or totally independent value(for example: current date `datetime.now`), then you can use that.

Comment: It seemed reasonable and it didn't work for me. Reason: a typo in your sample: "scrore" -> score. Now works.